# Rounding the output issue with SAS DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, sas, db2, proc

I am running db2 sql in SAS via a passthru and that is working fine. The issue I am having is getting my output to round. I have tried different options via format= but cant get desired results.

```
PROC SQL;
        CREATE TABLE WORK.ISSUES1671 AS  
        SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO MYDB ( 

        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ISSUE_ID) AS ISSUE_ID,
            SUM(PAID_TO_DT_AMT) AS PAID_TO_DATE_YTD

        FROM LOD.RMD

            );
QUIT;
```

this gives me a table with this
ISSUE_ID    PAID_TO_DATE_YTD
3746    1015768311.9

I then have this:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT 
        sum(PAID_TO_DATE_YTD-843686339.02) AS PAIDOUT_YTD FORMAT= DOLLAR18.2
    FROM WORK.ISSUES1671;
QUIT;
```

which gives me this
$172,081,972.83 which is correct but I want it to round to $172.1

Any help or ideas on how I can get this to show?

Comment: Can you do the rounding in the Db2 query? see the ROUND() function.

Comment: Yes you can but when I try something like this
`PROC SQL;
SELECT ROUND(PAIDOUT_YTD, .1)
FROM WORK.ISSUES1672;
QUIT;`
I get 1.72136E8 as the output

Answer (score 0):

I think the round function works a bit differently in db2. Check out the documentation right here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-round

I suggest a DB2-SQL, that runs in db2 and not in SAS,  something like this:
SELECT ROUND(PAIDOUT_YTD, -5) FROM ;

Unfortunately, I do not have a db2 instance to prove it.